# Line breaks in HTML source when reading in text file with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

When reading in a text file via PHP as followed:

```
$file_handle = fopen("L:\\file.txt", "rb"); 
while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
{
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle); 
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text); 
    echo "<option value=\"$parts[0]\">$parts[0]</option>"; 
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

... the HTML source code ends up looking like:

```
<option value="AACM
">AACM
</option><option value="Academic Registry
">Academic Registry
</option><option value="Admin
">Admin
```

.. and so on. Very messy! Is there a way to prevent it? Ideally I'd like it formatted properly as:

```
<option value="AACM">AACM</option>
<option value="Academic Registry">Academic Registry</option>
```

... etc.

Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<option value=\"".trim($parts[0])."\">".trim($parts[0])."</option>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `trim()` function to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
$parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);
```

Acctuly an easier and faster way to read a file without doing something line by line is `file_get_contents()`
Example: `echo file_get_contents("L:\\file.txt");`

But if you want to read the file line by line heres an

```
<?php
$filename = "L:\\file.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Couldn't open $filename");
while(!feof($fp)) {
   $line = fgets($fp, 1024);
   echo "$line\n";
}
?>
```

Sources:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
http://www.codemiles.com/php-tutorials/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-php-t1484.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll definitely look into using this from now on instead :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try out, but i think this should work:

```
$file_handle = fopen("L:\\file.txt", "rb"); 
while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
{
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle); 
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text); 
    $option = "<option value=\"$parts[0]\">$parts[0]</option>";
    $new_option = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/","",$option) . "\n";
    echo $new_option;
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: I think this probably would work but I suspect trim might be more efficient. I've used the snippet given by looper. Thank you though!